# Hover effect to click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Heres basically what the code looks like, it should run if pasted in sublime, what i'm trying to do is get the div to show when the page is loaded and then hide on scroll but when the button is clicked it should show wherever you are on the page. The codes a bit rough but its just a test page

```js
 $(window).scroll(function() {
    
        if ($(this).scrollTop()>0)
         {
            $('.fade').fadeOut();
         }
        else
         {
          $('.fade').fadeIn();
         }
     });
 
 $(function(){
        $(".box").click(function(){
          $(this).find(".fade").fadeIn();
        }
                        ,function(){
                            $(this).find(".fade").fadeOut();
                        }
                       );        
    });
 
 window.onscroll = function()
    {
        var left = document.getElementById("left");
    
    
    
        if (left.scrollTop < 60 || self.pageYOffset < 60) {
            left.style.position = 'fixed';
            left.style.top = '60px';
        } else if (left.scrollTop > 60 || self.pageYOffset > 60) {
            left.style.position = 'absolute';
            left.style.margin-top = '200px';
        }
    
    }
```

```css
body {
  height: 2000px;    
}
.fade {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: #d15757;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
}
    
    
.box{color: red;}
    
#left{
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  height: 200px;
  background: yellow;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
<div class="fade" id="left">
    show div / hide on click (NOT HOVER)
</div>
    
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<div style="margin-left: 90% !important;">
<button style="    position: fixed;
        /* margin-right: -40% !important; */
        margin-top: 0%;
        background-color: red;
        color: #fff;
        padding: 10px 10px;
        display: block;
        width: 54%;
        float: right;
        top: 0;">show div again</button></div>
</div>
  
    <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js'>
```

Comment: Change the `.hover` to `.click` in the second line of ur code

Comment: Hey, tried that one already and no luck

Comment: Then please provide a working example of your code reproducing the issue so we can check and help you out. The info you provided is not enough.

Comment: hey thanks, the only problem is i have another short script running to hide the same div on scroll, the hover script was used to bring it back to wherever i am on the page but the click function isn't bringing it back but the hover works, tried to add the code to jsfiddle but no luck adding external scripts

Answer (score 1):

You can use `toggle` since you need to alternate `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` on click

Replace `hover`

```
 $(function(){
        $(".box").hover(function(){
          $(this).find(".fade").fadeIn();
        },function(){
           $(this).find(".fade").fadeOut();
        }
        );        
 });
```

With `toggle`

```
 $(function(){
        $(".box").toggle(function(){
          $(this).find(".fade").fadeIn();
        },function(){
           $(this).find(".fade").fadeOut();
        }
        );        
 });
```

Comment: I reviewed the API reference regarding .toggle, but it doesn't seem to have a pattern similar to yours: toggle(callback, callback). Wuts going on???

Answer (score 1):

This could work. If box is clicked, check if `.fade` element is already visible. If it is, then hide it, if not, show it.

```
$(".box").click(function(){
    if($(".fade", this).is(":visible"))
    {
        $(".fade", this).fadeOut();
    }
    else
    {
        $(".fade", this).fadeIn();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

a quick look at the doc would have saved you headaches: http://api.jquery.com/click

Answer (score 0):

It`s not working for reason - you create buttons dynamically because of that you need to call them with .live() method if you use jquery 1.7

but this method is deprecated (you can see the list of all deprecated method here) in newer version. if you want to use jquery 1.10 or above you need to call your buttons in this way:

```
$(document).on('click', 'selector', function(){ 
     // Your Code
});
```

Your code will be something like this.

```
$(document).on('click', '.box', function(){
     $(this).find(".fade").fadeIn();
 },function(){
     $(this).find(".fade").fadeOut();
 });
```